# Stop table cell content from wrapping on inner <small> element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I am trying to stop `<td>` content from wrapping. Table cell contains two numbers: value and its percentage. The second number shall be smaller and keep constant distance from the first one (whatever the value will be) so all will be better aligned for readability.

It works, however when resizing window at some point cell content starts to wrap, and `<small>` content is put in the new line.

I would like browser to treat both numbers, the whole cell content, as a one monolithic text.

I will be also happy with any other solution than `<small class="text-muted fixed-width-45px">` which will help to keep small number in the constant distance from the big one, as far as it solves wrapping issue same time.

I use Bootstrap 3.

```
<td class="text-right">123,00<small class="text-muted fixed-width-45px">(23%)</small></td>
```

CSS used for constant distance between two numbers:

```
.fixed-width-45px {
    width: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to the table cell.